# Changed Elastic Beanstalk protocols to TCP/SSL and now S3 connection no longer works

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parse-platform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently had to change the protocols on my dev server to enable `ParseLiveQuery` and I noticed that requests from the app no longer receive images and trying to save, also fails.

Requesting I get

> [Error]: Response status code was unacceptable: 403 (Code: 1, Version: 1.17.1)

Trying to save an image I get:

> [Error]: Could not store file. (Code: 130, Version: 1.17.1)
>   2018-08-16 14:22:54.361221-0400 myApp[83331:20699254] getting latest for sale
>   Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=130 "Could not store file." UserInfo={code=130, temporary=0, error=Could not store file., NSLocalizedDescription=Could not store file.})

Here is my port protocol settings:

[image]

And the code I'm trying to run to post

```
    let obj = PFObject(className: "GroupConvos")
        obj.setObject("The Picnic", forKey: "groupName")
        obj.setObject("zackshapiro created 'The Picnic'", forKey: "lastMessageText")
        obj.setObject("system", forKey: "lastMessageSender")

        let img = UIImage(named: "picnic")!
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.8)!
        let file = PFFile(name: "avatar", data: data)!
//        let file = try! PFFile(name: "avatar123456", data: data, contentType: "image/jpeg")
        file.saveInBackground { (completed, error) in
            print(error)
            if completed {
                obj.setObject(file, forKey: "groupImage")
                obj.saveInBackground(block: { (completed, error) in
                    if completed {
                        print("done")


                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

the s3 adapter code in my index.js hasn't changed

```
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
var s3Adapter = new S3Adapter(
    "my bucket",
    { directAccess: true,
      baseUrl: 'http://someURL1234.cloudfront.net'
    }
);
```

then I plug that into my `ParseServer` object.

Any idea what's going on here? The issue isn't present on production where the protocols are still HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by using the same port 80 for HTTPS (SSL) traffic and HTTP traffic. You will need to setup HTTPS and an SSL certificate on your backend.

When you enable TCP listeners (layer 4 listeners) in a load balancer, the LB just passes connections straight thru to your backend. This also means that SSL certificates will not be used at the LB (for TCP listeners), but instead must be setup at the backend server.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I need an HTTPS port open with the cert as well?

Comment: Correct. The SSL termination happens on your backend instead of at the LB.

Comment: Can I have that additional port at 443 as well or no?

Comment: Looks like no. How would you suggest I set this up with the existing ports so it all works together

Comment: HTTPS is port 443 (default). You can use any available port that you want but make sure you understand the implications. For normal web servers stay with HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443).

Comment: What I'm asking is: I need a TCP port for a WebSocket and sounds like I need HTTPS as well for S3 stuff. How would you recommend I configure all of this?

Comment: If you are using node.js, then you need to setup a secure listener process or thread. You have not provided information on your environment so I cannot answer. However, that is a different question. Mark this question solved and post a new question.

Comment: Will do. I am using node. New question coming shortly. Thanks John. Appreciate your help

Comment: Put the link to your next question here and I will follow it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885382/configuring-a-node-js-application-to-work-with-websockets-over-tcp-as-well-as-aw Here you go