# Configuring a Node.js application to work with Websockets over TCP as well as AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parse-platform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on a Node.js application and installing WebSockets to use with ParseLiveQuery. For the app to work in full, I need HTTPS access for S3, images, etc. and TCP access for the WebSocket.

Below is my current setup:

[image]

And my `index.js` file

```
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
var s3Adapter = new S3Adapter(
    "myAppMediaServer",
    { directAccess: true,
      baseUrl: 'http://myApp12345.cloudfront.net' // This could be your CloudFront URL
    }
);
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://name:othername@ds55555-a0.mlab.com:9999,ds02222-a1.mlab.com:44444/appprod?replicaSet=rs-ds019322',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
  javascriptKey: process.env.JAVASCRIPT_KEY, vars
  clientKey: process.env.CLIENT_KEY,
  facebookAppIds: ['12345678'],
  filesAdapter: s3Adapter,
  verbose: process.env.VERBOSE_KEY || false,
  allowClientClassCreation: process.env.CLIENT_CREATION || false,
  liveQuery: {
      classNames: ['GroupConvos', 'GroupMessages']
  },
  databaseOptions: { //defaults to 5 and caused bottlenecking issues
    poolSize: 500
  },
  maxUploadSize: "5mb"
});

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
var parseLiveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

I've been made aware that I need to change my 443 port back to HTTPS from a TCP instance protocol and I'm a bit confused about how to get this working precisely so that my app supports both TCP for sockets and HTTPS for everything else.

Thanks

**Edit**

Right now I have an HTTP listener on port 80. It sounds like I need to create another server at 443 like the code below. That's step 1, right?

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// new
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem')
};

const https = require('https');
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);
httpsServer.listen(443, function() {
    console.log('ParseServer running on port 443 with SSL.');
});
var parseLiveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpsServer);
```

Then what is the configuration on my AWS load balancer to allow for HTTPS connections (so that S3 file get/post) works and what is the secure TCP configuration such that I'm using `wss` to run my socket?

Answer (score 0):

In a simple example you need to do something like this. I am showing the Let's Encrypt style of SSL certificates, which I do recommend. I also recommend just using HTTPS today and not using HTTP at all (or just redirect HTTP to HTTPS).

```
var https = require('https')

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem')
};

var httpsServer = require('https').createServer(options,app);

httpsServer.listen(443, function() {
    console.log('ParseServer running on port 443 with SSL.');
});

var parseLiveQueryServerSecure = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpsServer);
```

Comment: You cannot use AWS SSL Certifications for your own services. AWS does not provide you with the Private Key. If you have your own SSL certificates that match the domain name, they will work. Just change the options above to load the private key and certificate chain files.

Comment: What I still don't understand is how the TCP configuration fits into this so that the sockets will work appropriately

Comment: It does not fit in - meaning that you have two independent networking processes working. One for HTTP and one for HTTPS. Configure each one with the service that you desire. TCP is a layer 4 protocol. HTTP and HTTPS are layer 7 protocols that sit on top of layer 4. In your code you have created an HTTP listener. My code, which is an addition, creates the HTTPS listener. Think of it as your home with two telephone numbers. You can reach the house via either telephone. When you setup a LB TCP Listener on port 443, you need to setup a listener for HTTPS on your backend (your 2nd phone line).

Comment: after a few days of research and mulling this over, I've clarified the question a bit if you wouldn't mind taking a look. Thanks!

Comment: For your load balancer (ELB) you will add another listener for port 443 (HTTPS). If you are using ALB create another Target Group for 443 (HTTPS). Your goal is to configure your load balancer to listen on port 80 (HTTP) and forward to port 80 (HTTP) AND listen on port 443 (HTTPS) and forward to port 443 (HTTPS).

Comment: Is the dual listener setup in my code above correct? This is the new configuration for the load balancer as you've recommended (minus TCP): https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2g2k3X1q0r2r023E0R0h/%5B424c4a1d9105edd6a9198a31e5e2f008%5D_Screen+Shot+2018-08-20+at+4.51.24+PM.png?v=2031a89e. What port/instance should the TCP listener be set for in my ELB config?

Comment: Read my previous comment

Comment: I have. My ELB looks like 443/HTTPS -> 443/HTTPS, 80/HTTP -> 80/HTTP. Layer 7 (HTTP(S)) sits on top of Layer 4 (TCP). What I'm not understanding, and I apologize if I'm not asking this in the right way, is how TCP is handled with this configuration. Is it automatically available via these two ports because HTTP(S) sits on top of TCP?

Comment: I am confused why you are mentioning Layer 4? You only need to configure Layer 7. There are two types of listeners: Layer 4 and Layer 7. For HTTPS you can either use Layer 4 or Layer 7 but not both at the same time - well you can for more complicated multi-load balancer implementations but that is overkill for your project.

Comment: Because I don't know what I'm doing yet :) I think I figured it out though. thanks John